# Ping printer in VPN

Tags: ipv4, vpn, ping

Sorry for a dump question. I am able to ping printer in my company with following shell:

```
ping print226
```

**Question:** How does router solve this since it doesn't have domain name? Will it work for whole `VPN` or just it applies to my `physical network`?

Comment: You are pinging a hostname so this will be resolved to an IP address. So when you are connected to your VPN, your interface will be configured to use a DNS server to resolve any names to IP. If a record exists on this DNS server for print226, and there is a route to the device, you can ping it. Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does router solve this since it doesn't have domain name?

Since you're pinging the printer in the LAN, DNS lookup is performed for the local domain.

> Will it work for whole VPN or just it applies to my physical network?

It depends on how your VPN is configured, but normally, yes. A VPN allows you to connect to an internal network just like you're physically there.